# Интернационализация MFC

Tags: i18n, mfc, c++

Дано: приложение в разработке с интерфейсом на MFC.

Требуется: прикрутить к нему перевод в 2 клика: выбрал язык -> кликнул Ok -> приложение полностью на этом языке (без перезагрузки и т.д.).

Реквестирую начинающих и опытных программистов поделится мыслями и опытом. Про рекомендации делать сей перевод ресурсной длл вкурсе.

Answer (score 1):

Понятно, что полное изменение текущего языка означает обновление всех контролов сверху вниз. Соответственно, такую возможность необходимо учитывать с самого начала при разработке архитектуры приложения, иначе вы рискуете получить огромную проблему.

---

Вообще, локализация MFC приложений руками - это большая и достаточно сложная задача, которая, к сожалению, не имеет универсального решения. Если вы хотите добавить интернационализацию в уже имеющийся продукт, то есть, грубо гвооря, в продакшн, то лично я бы смотрел в сторону коммерческих солюшенов типа [appTranslator.](http://www.apptranslator.com/)

Если все-таки руками - то любой контрол придется помечать как `IInternalizable` и реализовывать в нем методы типа `UpdateAllVisibleInternationalizableLabelsAndText`, поскольку задача обновления контрола с учетом подтягивания специфичных для локали строчек не решается для уже имеющегося множества MFC контролов без введения вспомогательных абстракций.

Comment: apptranlator суть редактор ресурсов. Повторюсь исходное приложение в разработке, на стадии введения интернационализации.
Как я понял, вы предлагаете расширить функционал MFC-контролов, фактически унаследовав от каждого, приведя всех к интерфейсу, пригодному для обновления? Как быть с контролами, которые не имеют возможности смены в рантайм? Как быть с теми, которые создаются неявно? Как правило текст в контролах задается при конструировании, что при наследовании сильно усложняет такой подход и требует введения спец inplace-фабрик или потребует даже type-erasure.

Comment: Как поступить? Выходит что так даже сложнее.

Comment: @Dith Сложнее чем **что?** Вы знаете какие-то альтернативные способы добиться описываемого поведения ( в первую очередь, обновление без перезагрузки)?

Comment: Вопрос про то и был, как сделать без перезагрузки. Некоторые отмеченные мной моменты в вашем предложении требуют разъяснения, иначе выходит что предложенным вами способом сделать таки нельзя.

Answer (score 0):

Сложность в том, что длина строк в разных языках разная и элементы на определенных языках будут наползать друг на друга? Мне кажется, что в самом простом варианте достаточно преобразовать проект в Unicode и таскать за собой несколько таблиц строчек по одной на язык и из нее просто подгружать caption'ы для компонентов. Получается, прикрутить поддержку многоязыковости к MFC можно, но это очередной велосипед. Например, товарищи делали так: [1](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11731/Resource-DLLs-and-Language-Selection-Menu), [2](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10542/Easily-Load-and-Format-Strings-from-the-String-Tab)